# Button press adds digit to input element, but input text does not scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I make a calculator on my website. But I encountered a problem. When the text is wider than the input width, the text is added correctly, but we can't see it. Note that when we do not press a button but enter it from the keyboard, it works, but I need to press them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--CSS3-->
    <style>
        #result {
            width: 100px;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: large;
        }
    </style>

    <!--HTML5-->
    <input type="text" id="result">
    <button id="addSeven">7</button>
    <button id="addEight">8</button>

    <!--JavaScript-->
    <script>
        var result = document.getElementById("result");
        var button7 = document.getElementById("addSeven");
        var button8 = document.getElementById("addEight");

        button7.onclick = function() {
            result.value += "7";
        }
        button8.onclick = function() {
            result.value += "8";
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question title shouldn't be a scenario the leads up to a problem, it should be a short statement of the problem itself. What actual problem are you having?

Comment: It is also unclear from your main question's text what should happen and what is incorrectly happening now. Please edit your question and take the time to clearly explain what should happen and what is wrong with what is happening now. * it appears, but we can't see it* doesn't make any sense. If it appears, then you can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to use `.focus()` after every entry:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var button7 = document.getElementById("addSeven");
var button8 = document.getElementById("addEight");

button7.onclick = function() {
  result.value += "7";
  result.focus();
}
button8.onclick = function() {
  result.value += "8";
  result.focus();
}
```

```css
#result {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result">
<button id="addSeven">7</button>
<button id="addEight">8</button>
```

**Update**

If you want the text to stay on the end after lost the focus, you can set the `scrollLeft` property to the end of the input:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var button7 = document.getElementById("addSeven");
var button8 = document.getElementById("addEight");

button7.onclick = function() {
  result.value += "7";
  result.scrollLeft = result.scrollWidth;
}
button8.onclick = function() {
  result.value += "8";
  result.scrollLeft = result.scrollWidth;
}
```

```css
#result {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result">
<button id="addSeven">7</button>
<button id="addEight">8</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when we focus the button, the text appears that is out of focus

Comment: If you put the focus elsewhere, the input will return to the beginning of the text, it's normal and happens even when you type from the keyboard and focusing on other elements.

Comment: And it can`t be solved?

Comment: Check my update.